# Android app error glUtilsParamSize: unknow param

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I wanted to create a first page to my application in which you must log in/register successfully to facebook in order to take you to the next Intent. I've followed the tutorial from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android, but i've couldn't implement what was on point 3. (if i did that, then it wouldn't show me anything, just a blank screen). If i run it now, it shows me the facebook button, but when I click on it and it gets me to the login page, if I want to type anyhing in the boxes I get errors like:

```
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000d (glSizeof,73)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000d (glSizeof,73)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000d (glSizeof,73)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000d (glSizeof,73)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000d (glSizeof,73)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000d (glSizeof,73)
```

This is my java file:

```
public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity {
    // @Override
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);  
    }

    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_log_in, container, false);
                    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
                    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
                    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            // App code
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // App code
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            // App code
                        }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

I've also added what was in that tutorial for the AndroidManifest.xml file and strings.xml

Comment: It works now, but I've still got those errors

Answer (score 8):

This error is from the Android simulators OpenGL rendering engine and not from your code. You can change the rendering settings inside simulators options under settings -> advanced.

But from other threads people reported problems can persist, which was the case for me too.

Another very useful solution is to add a new logcat filter inside Android Studio. This way you can exclude noisy log messages **and** keep the log to their app only.

[image: New Logcat Filter Settings]

Add your exclusions to **Log Tag** like this: *^(?!(eglCodecCommon|tagToExclude))*

Add your package name or prefix to **Package Name**: *com.mycompany.*

This way it is possible to filter for as many strings you like **and** keep the log to your package.